# My Steam license agreement when I activate a game is just a list of directories

Tags: steam

For about a year, whenever I activated a Humble Bundle game on Steam, it would give me a blank license agreement to agree to. I thought it was slightly odd.

Today I got this instead:
[image]

That's the contents of my Games directory.

What's this, and am I the only one seeing a rather odd product activation license agreement?

Comment: Maybe this shows up because steam could not find the path to the license.

Comment: Probably something wrong with your Steam installation, though it doesn't seem like something worth reinstalling Steam for.

Comment: @RossRidge Unless if they want to actually read the license.

Comment: @AngusAtkinson http://store.steampowered.com/subscriber_agreement/

Comment: I don't particularly want to read the agreement, in fact I wonder if this could be used as a reasonable defence in court. I only ever agreed to a blank screen and a directory listing... :) Only issue is there's no reason for me to find myself in court in the first place, which is not a bad thing, but makes this curiosity useless...

Comment: Did you try that print button at the bottom? I wanna see what it prints :)

Comment: As already said, this can only mean that that screen usually searches for the agreement, and in this case didn't find any so it left you with a directory screen.

Comment: @user107214 Likely not unfortunately. The license terms specify the "Steam Subscriber Agreement". It's very well possible that you could make a decent argument in court, but those people are very picky about the specific wording.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some (boopity-boop-boop) research, I managed to find this excerpt from a older post but with the same issue:

> ... it is an error on your installation, as when we update our client... updates >the license file in your ...

It's nothing to worry about. I'd simply agree and continue.